# react native splash screen transition to initial screen different in android

Tags: android, react-native

I have been working on a project using react-native-splash-screen to display a splash screen while the app is loading.

The issue is that in iOS once the app is finished loading the splash screen gets replaced with the initial screen of the app without anything happening in between. But, when I run it in android for some reason once the app loads, the splash screen shrinks a little (black borders showing) then it fades out as the initial screen fades in while sliding from the bottom.

How do I stop android version from doing that? I have been trying to find out where are these animations coming from but can't figure it out.

```
@Override
public LinearLayout createSplashLayout() {
    LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
    view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    TextView bottomTextView = new TextView(this);

    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //bottomTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    bottomTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    textView.setText("main text");
    bottomTextView.setText("second text");
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    bottomTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40);
    bottomTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
    bottomTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    view.addView(textView);
    view.addView(bottomTextView);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: what react-native libary that you used for splash screen?

Comment: react-native-splash-screen

Comment: are you using a image or text for your splash screen?

Comment: did u hide the splash screen in ur initial screen?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I have for the splash screen

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing, but not using react-native-spash-screen at all...

Comment: Did you try `SplashScreen.hide();` in `componentDidMount()` as per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen#usage)?